# Trouble with rigify: Can someone rig for me?

Tags: rigging, rigify

hellooo guuuys im new to the world of animation.

i use bforartists because its easy to use instead of that hotkey blender crap. so my problem is. i work on an female character and i have riged her with rigify. i set the bones like in the tutorials, than i click on "generate rig" and than the rig is messed up? why? and even when i select my mesh and than the rig with "parenting-automatic keying" it didnt work. the rig that i set properly is smaller and wider and my character doesnt move at all.

**i tried everything! can someone rig it for me and send me back please? the bones are already set.** and/or tell me what im doing wrong...

download it: https://www12.zippyshare.com/v/jMuDAKeH/file.html

attention: the girl is nude haha!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a job assignment, not a question

Comment: A few things you should do differently when writing your questions to better your chanses of getting help. #1 don't start of by bashing blender (there really are a lot of blender only fans) #2 This is a Q and A site, we do not download files and fix them for people. Getting an answer saying what is wrong is a bit different. Questions and answers should help more then just one person. #3 please only use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com for blend hosting. (In 30 days your question will be completely useless because zippyshare will of deleted your file.)

Answer (score 7):

We won't do your work for you. We will only help you with answers to your questions.

First thing I noticed, both your mesh and metarig have unapplied scales (and uneven for the metarig). They also have unapplied rotations. You have to apply your objects scales and rotations via <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> before doing anything.